# Php schedule seconds task

Tags: php, schedule

For example:

```
$task->schedule(3500,$func);

function func(){ //do something}
```

How to implement schedule to execute callback function after `3500` seconds?

Comment: can you flesh the question out a little please

Answer (score 0):

It's better if you make Cron Jobs:

Method to create Crob Job for every minute:

```
login in to server using ssh ..
type crontab -e
*/1 * * * * php SCRIPT_NAME --> this will run every minute
```

Comment: I want a function to exceute my function by seconds ,ex:30 seconds.

Comment: @敬錞潘 You mean you want to run something every 30 seconds or only once after 30 seconds?